# how to position a Latex/tikz rotated text?

Tags: tikz-pgf, alignment, vertical

The code :

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (-3,0)--(3,0) node [below] {\scriptsize $\Omega$} ;

\draw (0,0) node[below]{0} node [below=3mm]{(a)}--(0,3) node[right]{\scriptsize $X_s(j\Omega)$};

\draw [-latex](2,0) node [below, rotate=-90] {\scriptsize $16000\pi$} --(2,1.5) node [right]{$\frac{\pi}{T}$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Tries to place vertical text directly under a vertical line. The text shows up slightly to the left with its center aligned to the bottom of the line. How do I place the vertical text directly under the vertical line?

Comment: Options like [below] are rotation sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

You need to select an appropriate anchor, `west` in this case.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={font=\scriptsize}]

\draw (-3,0)--(3,0) node [below] {$\Omega$} ;

\draw (0,0) node[below]{0} node [below=3mm]{(a)}--(0,3) node[right]{$X_s(j\Omega)$};

\draw [-latex](2,0) node [ rotate=-90,anchor=west] {$16000\pi$} --(2,1.5) node [right]{$\frac{\pi}{T}$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note also that it is advantageous to use `font=\scriptsize` instead of putting `\scriptsize` in the node contents, and if you want to apply this to all nodes use `nodes={font=\scriptsize}`.

Comment: or with `anchor=east`: `\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={font=\scriptsize}]
\draw (-3,0)--(3,0) node [below] {$\Omega$} ;
\draw (0,0) node[below]{0} 
            node [below=3mm]{(a)}--(0,3) node[right]{$X_s(j\Omega)$};
\draw [-latex] (2,0) node [ rotate=90,anchor=east] {$16000\pi$} --(2,1.5) node [right]{$\frac{\pi}{T}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`